# How to remove duplicate object from array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on an array, Actually, I have a dropdown list. I am pushing that object into an array but I am facing one issue actually when I select something it shows two elements at the same time like in dropdown let suppose if I have options ( option1, option2, option3). For example, I have selected option1 it pushed object value as option1 but when I select option2 it also pushed it into an array. I want unique values like if I select options2 it should be select recent value.

```
 generateExtraFieldData = (data, name, index, type, value, values) => {
const { projectFloorData, unitModifiedData } = this.state
let obj = projectFloorData[name]
obj['data'] = data
let tempArr = [...unitModifiedData]

tempArr.push(obj)

this.setState({ unitModifiedData: this.uniqueFiles(tempArr) })

// projectFloorData[name].data = data
```

}

```
 uniqueFiles = (data) => {
    let unique = _.uniqBy(data, 'index')
    console.log('@@ array', unique)
    return unique
  }
```

I have used lodash but it just return ist selected value, I need a recent value like if the user selected a second time

Comment: Trying to be as respectful as possible: All your questions seem to be "I have an emergency", but it seems that you don't really have a great understanding the language or the tools you're using. You can't keep using "I'm a beginner" as an excuse to not understand the things you're meant to be working on. Sometimes you have to put the work in and learn.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `yourArray.length = 1;`, this limit you array to an int limit. And if you select another option, just do `yourArray.length = 0` to clear the array and then again `yourArray.length = 1;` to store the new option.

Comment: Can you please edit this code I am sorry I am beginner to JS

Comment: Could you please edit my code as I need it urgent.

Comment: is "tempArr" the array you put the objects on?

Comment: Yes.... it is ,

Answer (score 1):

why are you pushing your selected value into your array if you want to select a single value at a time try an object instead of an array and change the value/ reassign the value on selection.

Comment: and if the problem is just it's inserting the same value then first try to filter the array with the key of the value and then check if length > 0 then don't push else push  the object into the array;

Comment: Can you please edit my code as I am beginner. I need to reoslve this task . thanks

Comment: Can you please share the exact sample data